# Android Preferences custom layout edit

Tags: android, layout, textview, preferences, preferenceactivity

I added custom layouts to my preferences. But now I want to change the text of a `TextView` inside a layout programmatically. How do I do that?

Now it looks like this:

```
final PreferenceScreen preference = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(getString(R.string.key_of_my_prefernce));
preference.setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_preference);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
PreferenceManager prefmngr=preference.getPreferenceManager();
TextView txt = (TextView)prefmngr.findPreference("the key of the textview in the preference tree").getView(convertView, parent);
txt.setText("TEXT");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

Comment: hm, I tried. But it says some kind of LinearLayout CastException. The only thing I change was to add the key of the layout in findPreference() and i wrote getView(findViewByID(R.id.textView),null)

Comment: @nikola this is saved my life

Comment: @nikola what would you hand in as the convertView argument?

Comment: also, I don't understand how this solution if you have multiple preferences using your custom preference type. In that case, the text view's id will no longer be unique in the tree correct?